# How to use socket.io in Azure Worker Role?

Tags: node.js, azure, socket.io

I have been trying to set up a socket server in an Azure Worker Role but nothing seems to be working. I was trying to get this simple tutorial to function. This is the server.js file:

```
var port = process.env.port || 81;

var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app)

app.listen(port);
console.log('socket.io server started on port: ' + port + '\n');

function handler (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('socket.io server started on port: ' + port + '\n');
}

// io.configure(function () { 
//   io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]); 
//   io.set("polling duration", 10); 
// });

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('user connected');

  socket.on('sendMessage', function(data){
    console.log('user sent the message: ' + data.message + '\n');
    socket.emit('helloBack', { message: 'Hello back!' });
  });
});
```

With the following client:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Socket Test</title>
    <meta name="description" content="The azure socket tutorial">


    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.4.js"></script>
    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"   integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var socket;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#startButton").click(function () {
                $("#returnMessageLabel").empty();
                if (!socket) {
                    socket = io.connect("http://127.0.0.1:80/");
                    socket.on('helloBack', function (data) {
                        $("#returnMessageLabel").text(data.message);
                    });
                }
                socket.emit('sendMessage', { message: 'Hello there!' });
            });
        });  
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Click to introduce yourself</h1>
    <button id="startButton">Say Hello</button>
    <label id="returnMessageLabel"></label>
</body>
</html>
```

It works fine in the AzureEmulator on port 80, but when I publish the role I get the message 'socket.io server started on port: 80' but the client can't connect to send the sendMessage. I got this tutorial from https://dzone.com/articles/windows-azure-web-worker-roles

The follow is my ServiceDefinition.csdef file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ServiceDefinition xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" name="dzoned" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition">
  <WorkerRole name="WorkerRole1">
    <Startup>
      <Task commandLine="setup_worker.cmd &gt; log.txt" executionContext="elevated">
        <Environment>
          <Variable name="EMULATED">
            <RoleInstanceValue xpath="/RoleEnvironment/Deployment/@emulated" />
          </Variable>
          <Variable name="RUNTIMEID" value="node" />
          <Variable name="RUNTIMEURL" value="http://az413943.vo.msecnd.net/node/0.6.20.exe" />
        </Environment>
      </Task>
      <Task commandLine="node.cmd .\startup.js" executionContext="elevated" />
    </Startup>
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="HttpIn" protocol="tcp" port="80" />
      <InputEndpoint name="SocketIn" protocol="http" port="81" />
    </Endpoints>
    <Runtime>
      <Environment>
        <Variable name="PORT">
          <RoleInstanceValue xpath="/RoleEnvironment/CurrentInstance/Endpoints/Endpoint[@name='HttpIn']/@port" />
        </Variable>
        <Variable name="EMULATED">
          <RoleInstanceValue xpath="/RoleEnvironment/Deployment/@emulated" />
        </Variable>
      </Environment>
      <EntryPoint>
        <ProgramEntryPoint commandLine="node.cmd .\server.js" setReadyOnProcessStart="true" />
      </EntryPoint>
    </Runtime>
  </WorkerRole>
</ServiceDefinition>
```

Comment: If you're opening that client html in your computer's browser, 127.0.0.1:80 isn't the address you're going to want. You want the IP / port of the azure worker.

Comment: Well yes, When I use the URL and the port it doesn't work. I just get the message started on port 80. Also the io.configuration section I commented out seems to stop it from all together.

Comment: Did you set up an endpoint that maps external-to-internal port?

Comment: No I don't think so. I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: @Brian endpoints are fundamental to worker (and web) roles, and if you don't have any idea what they are, a quick web search would be very valuable to you. Without endpoints, you have no communication from the outside world.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to configure the endpoint of the worker role in your cloud service. Open the `ServiceDefinition.csdef` in your cloud service project, add the endpoint configuration under the worker role definition.

E.G.

```
<WorkerRole name="WorkerRole1" vmsize="Small">
    <Endpoints>
      <InputEndpoint name="HttpIn" protocol="http" port="81" />
    </Endpoints>
...
</WorkerRole>
```

And then package your project and deploy to Azure. Please refer https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-enable-communication-role-instances/ for more info.

Any update, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Added that line but it still isn't working. I attached the contents of ServiceDefinition.csdef file.

Comment: I ended up using an Azure Web App